# PDO While loop causing infinite loop

Tags: php, css, pdo, while-loop, infinite-loop

I have a PDO object to connect to a database to display properties and I was experimenting with displaying a message if no rows were found using an if statement. the message works, however when results are found, the loop is returning endless rows and breaks my css.

The only time it worked is when I defined my loop condition inside the loop brackets but then my if statement condition returns a "undefined variable error". How can I make both work together, I have looked at other questions and tried different things but haven't gotten anywhere.

//code

```
<?php function connectDB () {

    global $hostname, $db, $user, $pass;

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname; dbname=$db; charset=utf8", $user, $pass, array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

    if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'sales.php')) {
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM DATABASE.property WHERE (bit1&33=33 and sendToPortals ='0') and (addressToDisplay like ? or fullDetails like ?) ORDER BY pricePerWeek ASC";
    }
    else if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'lettings.php')) {
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM DATABASE.property WHERE bit1&17=17 and (addressToDisplay like ? or addressToDisplay like ?) ORDER BY pricePerWeek ASC";
    }

    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array('%Bedford Court Mansions%','%Adeline Place%')); 
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    $r = $query->fetch();

        if (!$r) {
        echo 'We have successfully Sold 
            all their current property within Bedford Court Mansions, WC1 and urgently require 
            new apartments for sale.
            Call us now on 020 72459 3345, if you are considering 
            selling your property.';
        } 
        else { 

        while ($r): 

            $address = $r['addressToDisplay']; 
            $beds = $r['bedrooms'];
            $price = $r['price_week_min'];
            $summary = $r['summary'];
            $image = $r['mainImage'];
            $area = $r['addressAlias'];
            $id = $r['id'];

            $address1 = str_replace(' ','-',$address);
            $address2 = str_replace(',','',$address1);
?>

    <li class="property">
        <div class="image-wrapper overlay-fade-in">
            <img src="http://www.hurford-salvi-carr.co.uk/pss/image-resize?height=257&width=449&black=1&reflection=0&prop=0&asset=pictures&file=<?php echo $image; ?>" />
            <div class="image-overlay-content">
                <h2>
                    <a href="http://www.hurford-salvi-carr.co.uk/property-for-sale/<?php echo strtolower(str_replace(' ','-',$area)); ?>/<?php echo strtolower(str_replace(' ','-',$address)); ?>/<?php echo $id; ?>" target="_blank">Find out More</a>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="property-content">
            <h3><?php echo $address; ?></h3>
            <p><strong>£ <?php echo number_format($price); ?> </strong></p>
            <p><strong><?php echo $beds; ?> &nbsp; Beds</strong></p>
            <p>
                <?php echo substr($summary, 0, 263); ?>...</p>
            <a href="http://www.hurford-salvi-carr.co.uk/property-for-sale/<?php echo strtolower(str_replace(' ','-',$area)); ?>/<?php echo strtolower(str_replace(' ','-',$address)); ?>/<?php echo $id; ?>" target="_blank">Click here to find out more</a>
        </div>
    </li>

<?php           
        endwhile; }}
?>
```

Comment: Basically, this happens because the variable `$r` is always set, so the `while`-loop is kind of `while (true):`. Just replace the parameter with `while ($r = $query-fetch()):`

Comment: Thanks for responding, yes that is how it was before but then i can't get the if statement to work correctly, I have tried putting the statement inside the loop but it doesn't echo anything

Comment: can you say print_r( $r); returns what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, the root of your issue is that you always check for a variable in your `while` statement, not the actual `fetch()` method. This will in turn look something like `while (true)`, which creates an infinite loop of the first row returned from your database.

To check if there was any results from the database, check the number of rows that was returned by your `SELECT` query, and if it's not 0, you can loop through the results. If it was 0, display a nice message telling them that there was nothing found.

```
<?php 
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array('%Bedford Court Mansions%','%Adeline Place%')); 
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$numRows = $query->rowCount();

if ($numRows == 0) {
    // No rows returned from database
} else { 
    // We have results!
    while ($query->fetch()): 
        // Loop through it all
?>
```

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: Thank you so much, that works perfectly, just a quick question, on php manual it say that rowCount() on a SELECT statement is not guaranteed to work on all databases, how would you know which database support it?

Comment: I haven't really looked into that, so I'm not 100% sure. But if you want to know if it's supported by your database or not, just run it once and control the output with the database - if it's correct, then your database is supported.